# passing array as a parameter - ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

#### This is inside the region controller file

```
def create
    postal_code_list = params[:region].delete(:postal_code_list)
    @region = Region.new(params[:region])
    authorize! :create, @region
    assign_postal_codes(postal_code_list)
```

#### This is inside the seed file

```
region = Region.create({
     name: "region1",
     postal_code_list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
})
```

I am attempting to create a few default values for a web app in testing. I am exceptionally new to ruby, so that is the reason for such a basic question.
When I run in debug mode, the page displays the name:region1, however the postal codes do not show up. I'm unsure as to how to pass the postal_code_list array into the controller file. What am I missing?

Comment: The seeds and the controller are not related at all. The seeds creates the Region entries in the database with: rake db:seed in the command line.

Comment: What does your database schema look like? Are you using Postgres arrays or a serialized column?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create seed for regions with seed run this steps:

in seeds.rb

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].each do |rc| 
  Region.create(name: "region#{rc}", postal_code_list: rc}
end
```

And then in the command line:

```
rake db:seed
```

This will create 10 regions named: "region1", "region2"... and postal_code_list: 1, 2...

Your controller is doing nothign as Region.create is doing a query, not a request.